# How to relabel/translate a Payment Method on Sales Order page

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, localisation

**Task**

I'm trying to translate "**Check / Money order**" to "**Quote**" in the Backend of Magento 2. This label is displayed on the `Sales > Order` screen after taking a payment with this method.

[image]

**Tried Methods**

So I've updated the following fields/files, but they don't have any effect on this particular instance.

1. Updated `en_US` but this only affects the translation under `Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods`
2. Updated the Title, which only affects the store view

Comment: Do you wanto show this title only in Admin grid?

Comment: Yeah, just on that screen. It's the only place I've seen the Method that hasn't been affected by the translation file.

Comment: I have same problem and i would like to rename the payment methods.
Can you provide a step by step guide?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148490)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it this way:

1. In your custom module create file VENDOR/MODULE/etc/config.xml with content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <checkmo>
                <title>Your custom title</title>
            </checkmo>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

2. Enable Module, Clear cache, etc...

Comment: thx for this smart answere. helped me a lot with after migrate from m1 to m2. Cause all payment methodes got renamed and so i can match to the old one